# How to convert a collection/ array into JSONArray using stream in java 8

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

Im having a double array , I need to convert the array into a `JSONArray` using java `streams`. I tried using forEach (shared mutability) which leads to loss of data.

```
public static JSONArray arrayToJson(double[] array) throws JSONException{
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    
    Arrays.stream(array)
         .forEach(jsonArray::put);  

    return jsonArray;
}
```

Is there any way I could to create `JSONArray` using streams?

Comment: What do you mean by "loss of data"?

Comment: Your code works fine and no data lost.

Comment: what JSon library you are using!

Comment: when i use parallel stream there some loss @zhh

Comment: Im having 1000 elements in my double array, the resulting JSONArray contains less than 1000 elements. @Zefick

Comment: why you use parallel stream, for what purpose ? and please edit your question and add this information, it's can make different.

Comment: ```JSONArray``` is not thread safe, you can see the documents.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your code works, but you can write something like this (`jdk 8+`):

```
return Arrays.stream(array)
             .collect(Collector.of(
                          JSONArray::new, //init accumulator
                          JSONArray::put, //processing each element
                          JSONArray::put  //confluence 2 accumulators in parallel execution
                     ));
```

one more example (create a `String` from `List<String>`)**:**

```
List<String> list = ...
String str = list.stream()
                 .collect(Collector.of(
                    StringBuilder::new,
                    StringBuilder::append,
                    StringBuilder::append,
                    StringBuilder::toString //last action of the accumulator (optional)  
                 ));
```

> Looks nice, but compiler complaints: `error: incompatible thrown types JSONException in method reference .collect(Collector.of(JSONArray::new, JSONArray::put, JSONArray::put)`

I checked this  on `jdk 13.0.1` and `JSON 20190722` and  didn't find problems except of `Expected 3 arguments, but found 1` in `.collect(...)`.

(*Gradle* : `implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20190722'`)

---

### Fix:

```
public static JSONArray arrayToJson(double[] array) throws JSONException {
    return Arrays.stream(array).collect(
            JSONArray::new,
            JSONArray::put,
            (ja1, ja2) -> {
                for (final Object o : ja2) {
                    ja1.put(o);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

**Note**: The combiner cannot be a method reference to just `JSONArray::put` because this will just put one array into the other (e.g. `[[]]`) instead of actually combining them as is the desired behavior.

Comment: Looks nice, but compiler complaints:

error: incompatible thrown types JSONException in method reference
.collect(Collector.of(JSONArray::new, JSONArray::put, JSONArray::put))

Answer (score 3):

`JSONArray` is not thread safe. If you are using parallel stream you should synchronize the operation.

```
Arrays
    .stream(array)
    .parallel()
    .forEach(e -> {
        synchronized(jsonArray) {
            jsonArray.put(e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you synchronize the operation, you don't need to use parallel, as you do not have any advantage of it.