# Stack sub Stack creation

Tags: java, collections, stack

How to create a stack within a stack? Like

```
[[1 2 3][3 4 5][6 7 8]]
```

So there are three substacks like `[123]`, `[456]`, `[789]` which sit within a main stack. How do I create it with stack build in function in Java?

Comment: You have this question tagged as `ArrayList` and `Stack`.  Which is it?

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  When you pop the outer stack, do you want to receive the entire substack as a `Stack` object?  That's just a `Deque<Deque<Integer>>`.  If that's not what you want, you'll have to clarify what happens on `push` and `pop`.

Comment: What does it mean: "stack build"?

Comment: I need to create a stack within a stack then want to sort and reverse the main stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Based upon the 1st element means 1,4,7. The order would be 7,4,1 but the other elements intact. So the result after sorting is [[7,8,9],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]]. If my stack was like that, like[ [1,10,5],[5,11,15],[4,9,2]]. After sorting I get the result like[[5,11,15],[4,9,2],[1,10,5]]. So that means only the 1st element will be sorted rest of same.

I think you can use `Comparator`(from *Java 8* it is `@FunctionalInterface`) for example :

```
    Stack<Stack<Integer>> stacks = new Stack<>();
    // Previous example
    // ...
    //straight Comparator
    Comparator<Stack<Integer>> byFirst = Comparator.comparingInt(Stack::firstElement);
    //reverse Comparator
    Comparator<Stack<Integer>> reverseByFirst 
           = (Stack<Integer> s1, Stack<Integer> s2)
                                   -> s2.firstElement().compareTo(s1.firstElement());
    // or  = (Stack<Integer> s1, Stack<Integer> s2)-> s2.get(0).compareTo(s1.get(0));

    // get Stack
    stacks = Stream.of(stackI1,stackI2,stackI3)
    //          .sorted(byFirst)       // byFirst
              .sorted(reverseByFirst)  // reverse
              .collect(Collector.of(
                           () -> new Stack(),
                           (s,b)->s.push(b),
                           (b1, b2) -> (Stack) b1.push(b2)
                       )
                  );
    System.out.println(stacks); //[[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I think it helps ...

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. But it work for 1st element and last element. Middle one as usual.[[2, 10, 5], [10, 5, 6], [5, 15, 9]]
[[5, 15, 9], [10, 5, 6], [2, 10, 5]]

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: i will try to check)))

Comment: Okkk Thank for your help

Comment: I checked **=>**  [stack.peek()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#peek()) - look here)))

Answer (score 0):

You can use **lambda expressions** (if I understood your question *right*):

```
    Stack<Integer> stackI1 = new Stack<>();
    stackI1.push(1);
    stackI1.push(2);
    stackI1.push(3);

    Stack<Integer> stackI2 = new Stack<>();
    stackI2.push(4);
    stackI2.push(5);
    stackI2.push(6);

    Stack<Integer> stackI3 = new Stack<>();
    stackI3.push(7);
    stackI3.push(8);
    stackI3.push(9);

    Stack<Stack<Integer>> stacks = new Stack<>();
    stack.push(stackI1);
    stack.push(stackI2);
    stack.push(stackI3);
    System.out.println(stacks); //[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
    /**
     *  lambda expressions
     */
    // stacks = stacks.stream() 
    stacks = Stream.of(stackI1,stackI2,stackI3)       
                  .collect(Collector.of(
                               () -> new Stack(),
                               (s,b)->s.push(b),
                               (b1, b2) -> (Stack) b1.push(b2)
                           )
                      );
    System.out.println(stacks); //[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Maybe it helps: [**example => Collector.of(...)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48145605/8030651) .

Comment: This code run perfectly. Whereas what is the meaning of Stack<Stack<Integer>> stack = new Stack<>();   expression.   However if I want to sort and reverse the stack [stack] what are the build in function Java ? I try Collection.sort but it's not working.It show two function Collection.lamda or Collection.class. How could I proceed?

Comment: How do you want to sort the Stack<>: like  `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` **=>** `[[9,8,7], [6,5,4], [3,2,1]]`, or `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` **=>** `[[7, 8, 9],[4, 5, 6],[1, 2, 3]]`, or else?

Comment: Based upon the 1st element means 1,4,7. The order would be 7,4,1 but the other elements intact. So the result after sorting is [[7,8,9],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]]. If my stack was like that, like[ [1,10,5],[5,11,15],[4,9,2]]. After sorting I get the result like[[5,11,15],[4,9,2],[1,10,5]]. So that means only the 1st element will be sorted rest of same.

Comment: public class New1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {int x=0,y=0,g=0,cost=1;fun1(x,y,g,cost);}public static int[] fun1(int x, int y, int g,int cost) {
        int [] a=new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            int x2=1,y2=1,g2=1;
             x = x2 + cost;
             y = y2 + cost;
            g = g2 + cost;
            a[0]=x;
            a[1]=y;
            a[2]=g;   }
        return (a);}    
This code unable to return updated value Which is x=2,y=2,g=2;I don't find any bug?then why it isn't update the value?

Comment: Please, write a bit separately)))

Comment: It is not possible to write separately in comment box.